# Making a pdf generator using iText7 library for android. Problem is that the app is generating pdf in android studio but not in my android phone

Tags: java, android, pdf-generation, itext7

The app is generating the pdf in AVD but when I am running it in my android device it is not generating the pdf.

Android device OS - 11

AVD 1 - 11 API 30

AVD 2 - Tiramisu API 33

App is working fine in both AVDs

I tried adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and this is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.invoicemaker'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.invoicemaker"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap_info.txt")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/MSungStd-Light.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/MSung-Light.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/STSong-Light.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/STSongStd-Light.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HYSMyeongJoStd-Medium.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HYGoThic-Medium.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HYSMyeongJo-Medium.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/KozMinPro-Regular.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/MHei-Medium.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HeiseiMin-W3.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/cjk_registry.properties")
        exclude("com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HeiseiKakuGo-W5.properties")
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.3'
}
```

This is my code :

```
package com.example.invoicemaker;

import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.RestrictionEntry;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageData;
import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.Border;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText nameEditText, numberEditText, addressEditText, dateEditText, priceEditText;
    private String name, phone, address, date, price;
    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nameEditText= findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        numberEditText= findViewById(R.id.phoneEditText);
        addressEditText= findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
        dateEditText= findViewById(R.id.invoiceDateEditText);
        priceEditText= findViewById(R.id.priceEditText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        name = nameEditText.toString();
        phone = numberEditText.toString();
        address = addressEditText.toString();
        date = dateEditText.toString();
        price = priceEditText.toString();

        if (!checkPermission()) {
            try {
                openActivity();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                requestPermissionAndContinue();
            } else {
                try {
                    openActivity();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private boolean checkPermission() {

        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ;
    }

    private void requestPermissionAndContinue() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.permission_necessary));
                alertBuilder.setMessage(R.string.storage_permission_is_encessary_to_wrote_event);
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                , READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
                Log.e("", "permission denied, show dialog");
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        } else {
        try {
            openActivity():
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (permissions.length > 0 && grantResults.length > 0) {

                boolean flag = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
                if (flag) {
                    try {
                        openActivity();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    finish();
                }

            } else {
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    private void openActivity() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
        File file = new File(path, "myPDF.pdf");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(String.valueOf(file));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

        //        TABLE 1

        float[] columnWidth1 = {280, 280};
        Table table1 = new Table(columnWidth1);

        Drawable d1 = getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
        Bitmap bmp1 = ((BitmapDrawable)d1).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream1);
        byte[] bitmapData1 = stream1.toByteArray();

        ImageData imageData1 = ImageDataFactory.create(bitmapData1);
        Image image1 = new Image(imageData1);
        image1.setWidth(100f);

        //  ROW 01
        table1.addCell(new Cell(3, 1).add(image1).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setMarginTop(50f));
        table1.addCell(new Cell(3, 1).add(new Paragraph("KALAM PUBLIC\nSCHOOL").setFontSize(20f)).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setMarginTop(90f).setMarginLeft(100f));
        //  ROW 02
        table1.addCell(new Cell(3, 1).add(new Paragraph("MANAGED BY\nTAMEER-E-NAU\nWELFARE TRUST")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setMarginTop(20f));
        table1.addCell(new Cell(3,1).add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 03
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("\n")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 04
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Invoice Date:").setBold()).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Invoice To:").setBold()).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));
        //  ROW 05
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("3/10/2023")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Mohd Ashfaq")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));



        //        TABLE 2

        float[] columnWidth2 = {280, 280};
        Table table2 = new Table(columnWidth2);

        //  ROW 01
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("DESCRIPTION")));
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("PRICE")));
        //  ROW 02
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Donate")));
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("10,000 INR")));
        //  ROW 03
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add(new Paragraph("\n")));
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add(new Paragraph("")));
        //  ROW 04
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2,1).add(new Paragraph("\n")));
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2,1).add(new Paragraph("")));
        //  ROW 05
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2,1).add(new Paragraph("\n")));
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2,1).add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 06
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("SUB TOTAL :").setBold()));
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("10,000 INR").setBold()));

        //        TABLE 3

        float[] columnWidth3 = {280, 280};
        Table table3 = new Table(columnWidth3);

        //  ROW 01
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("PAYMENT MODE - CASH").setBold()).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("CONTACT").setBold()).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 02
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("contact@tameerenautrust.com")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 03
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("+91 9198809256")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 04
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Lucknow Uttar Pradesh")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 05
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Pin Code 226020")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));

        document.add(table1);
        document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        document.add(table2);
        document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        document.add(table3);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        document.close();
    }
}
```

Before trying the code above, I was using this code :

```
package com.example.invoicemaker;

import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.RestrictionEntry;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageData;
import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.Border;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText nameEditText, numberEditText, addressEditText, dateEditText, priceEditText;
    private String name, phone, address, date, price;
    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nameEditText= findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        numberEditText= findViewById(R.id.phoneEditText);
        addressEditText= findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
        dateEditText= findViewById(R.id.invoiceDateEditText);
        priceEditText= findViewById(R.id.priceEditText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        name = nameEditText.toString();
        phone = numberEditText.toString();
        address = addressEditText.toString();
        date = dateEditText.toString();
        price = priceEditText.toString();

        try {
            createPDF();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createPDF() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
        File file = new File(path, "myPDF.pdf");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(String.valueOf(file));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

        //        TABLE 1

        float[] columnWidth1 = {280, 280};
        Table table1 = new Table(columnWidth1);

        Drawable d1 = getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
        Bitmap bmp1 = ((BitmapDrawable)d1).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream1);
        byte[] bitmapData1 = stream1.toByteArray();

        ImageData imageData1 = ImageDataFactory.create(bitmapData1);
        Image image1 = new Image(imageData1);
        image1.setWidth(100f);

        //  ROW 01
        table1.addCell(new Cell(3, 1).add(image1).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setMarginTop(50f));
        table1.addCell(new Cell(3, 1).add(new Paragraph("KALAM PUBLIC\nSCHOOL").setFontSize(20f)).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setMarginTop(90f).setMarginLeft(100f));
        //  ROW 02
        table1.addCell(new Cell(3, 1).add(new Paragraph("MANAGED BY\nTAMEER-E-NAU\nWELFARE TRUST")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setMarginTop(20f));
        table1.addCell(new Cell(3,1).add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 03
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("\n")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 04
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Invoice Date:").setBold()).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Invoice To:").setBold()).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));
        //  ROW 05
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("3/10/2023")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
        table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Mohd Ashfaq")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));

        //        TABLE 2

        float[] columnWidth2 = {280, 280};
        Table table2 = new Table(columnWidth2);

        //  ROW 01
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("DESCRIPTION")));
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("PRICE")));
        //  ROW 02
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Donate")));
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("10,000 INR")));
        //  ROW 03
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add(new Paragraph("\n")));
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add(new Paragraph("")));
        //  ROW 04
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2,1).add(new Paragraph("\n")));
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2,1).add(new Paragraph("")));
        //  ROW 05
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2,1).add(new Paragraph("\n")));
        table2.addCell(new Cell(2,1).add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 06
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("SUB TOTAL :").setBold()));
        table2.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("10,000 INR").setBold()));

        //        TABLE 3

        float[] columnWidth3 = {280, 280};
        Table table3 = new Table(columnWidth3);

        //  ROW 01
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("PAYMENT MODE - CASH").setBold()).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("CONTACT").setBold()).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 02
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("contact@XXXXXXXX.com")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 03
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("XXXXXXXXXX")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 04
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("XXXXXXX")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        //  ROW 05
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table3.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Pin Code 226020")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));

        document.add(table1);
        document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        document.add(table2);
        document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        document.add(table3);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        document.close();
    }
}
```

ERROR SHOWN IN LOG CAT :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/myPDF.pdf: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
at com.example.invoicemaker.MainActivity.createPDF(MainActivity.java:77)
at com.example.invoicemaker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8119)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8103)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1359)
```

AND MORE...

Comment: The file exists bur does not belong to your app.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Well is it true or not?

Comment: There is file permission issue